# When trying to run a dash board from github using heroku, my google drive authentication files can not be found, despite them being in the same folder

Tags: authentication, github, heroku, google-api

I have the token.json file containing the credentials for accessing my google drive using an API. When running the code locally on my computer, it runs fine. However, running the code from github, fails to find the file. I've tried a lot of things, putting the token file in the same directory, creating an absolute file path for the file to be found.

Here is my code at the moment:

```
def read_sheet(DOCUMENT_ID, sheet_name, path):

    '''return google sheet content as dataframe and worksheet object to write changes
    if sheet name not found, create blank sheet'''

    import gspread
    import pandas as pd
    import json
    import os

    credentials = path

    gc = gspread.oauth(
                       credentials_filename=credentials,
                       authorized_user_filename=credentials
                       )

    sh = gc.open_by_key(DOCUMENT_ID)

    try:
        worksheet = sh.worksheet(sheet_name)
    except:
        sh.add_worksheet(title=sheet_name, rows=1, cols=1)
        worksheet = sh.worksheet(sheet_name)

    print(fr"serving sheet: {sh.title}, {sheet_name}")

    df = pd.DataFrame(worksheet.get_all_records())

    return df, worksheet


with open("path.py") as f:
    exec(f.read())

#I created this path.py file so github could find the file from an absolute path - but it didn't work either. This is what that file contains: 

import os

absolute_path = os.path.dirname("__file__")
relative_path = "gspread\\token.json"
full_path = os.path.join(absolute_path, relative_path)


# and this is the line everything trips up on
df, ws = read_sheet("URI", "Sheet1", path=full_path)
```